# What's the purpose of systemd's exim4-base.timer?

Tags: systemd, exim

The content of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/exim4-base.timer` is

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily exim4-base housekeeping
Documentation=man:exim4(8)
Before=logrotate.timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
AccuracySec=12h
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

It talks about housekeeping and documentation at [`man 8 exim4`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/exim), but there is no visible action connected to this unit.

So, is this just some placeholder? Or am I missing something?

Just in case it is relevant, I am using Ubuntu 20.04, exim4 4.93 and systemd 245.

Comment: see 2.5.1. The daily cron job from http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/exim4-base/README.Debian.html

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, this is done via cron. But I don't see the connection to exim4-base.timer. Since cron already takes care of this, there's no need for some systemd timer.